# Generate image url for external users in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need generate image url for external access ionic app from public/storage/app/public/photos folder

I have tried to get image url via `url('/') . $path`.

```
$file      = $request->img_url; // get the validated file
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filename  = 'spot-image-' . time() . '.' . $extension;
$path      = $file->storeAs('photos', $filename);
$fields['img_url'] = url($path);
```

I want to store this url in db by `$fields['img_url']`.

Comment: And the question is??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way :

```
  if($request->hasFile('img_url')){
            $uniqueid=uniqid();
            $original_name=$request->file('img_url')->getClientOriginalName();

            $size=$request->file('img_url')->getSize();
            $extension=$request->file('img_url')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $name=time().'_'.$uniqueid.'.'.$extension;
            $imagepath=url('/storage/photos/'.$name);
            $path=$request->file('img_url')->storeAs('public/photos',$name);
            if($path){ 
                    $fields['img_url'] =$imagepath;
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi. this method give me http://ch.webapricot.am/photos/spot-image-1559660452.jpg this url, but it doesnt work

Comment: http://ch.webapricot.am/storage/photos/spot-image-1559661012.jpg it gives me tis link

Comment: @Asatur , have you created `php artisan storage:link` ??